# Laplace transform of $\int_t^{+\infty}\,\psi(\tau)\,d\tau$

Tags: laplace-transform

Why this equality?

$$\mathcal{L}\left(\int_t^{+\infty}\,\psi(\tau)\,d\tau\right)=\frac{1-\psi(s)}{s}$$

Can you help me with the steps?

Comment: Is $\psi(t)$ known? Whether or not this is true depends on what $\psi(t)$ is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Denoting $\Psi(t) = \int_t^\infty \psi(\tau) \, d\tau$, we have by definition of $\mathcal L$, that
\begin{align*}
  \mathcal L(\Psi)(s) &= \int_0^\infty \exp(-st)\Psi(t)\, dt\\
      &= \int_0^\infty \exp(-st)\int_t^\infty \psi(\tau)\, d\tau\, dt\\
      &= \int_0^\infty \int_t^\infty \exp(-st)\psi(\tau)\, d\tau\, dt\\
      &= \int_0^\infty \int_0^\tau \exp(-st)\psi(\tau)\, dt\, d\tau\\
      &= \int_0^\infty \int_0^\tau\exp(-st)\, dt\cdot \psi(\tau)\, d\tau\\
      &= \int_0^\infty \left(\frac 1s -\frac{1}s\exp(-s\tau)\right)\psi(\tau)\, d\tau\\ 
      &=\frac{\int_0^\infty \psi(\tau)\, d\tau - \mathcal L(\psi)(s)}{s}
\end{align*}
So your equation is true, if $\int_0^\infty \psi(\tau)\, d\tau = 1$ and $\mathcal L(\psi) = \psi$.

Comment: Is $\int_0^\infty \psi(\tau)\, d\tau = 1$ and $\mathcal L(\psi) = \psi$ ?

Comment: I don't know anything about the given $\psi$, in the OP this is not mentioned, perhaps it was just forgotten. In general, we cannot assume it.